# How to fetch other users media by Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

How can I fetch other users media through Instagram API, I can easily fetch my media through API. But how can I fetch others users. For fetching my medias I am using 
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=' . $token;
But when I try to others users media through username it gives no result.I have also replace "self" with username.But getting no result. I tried many solutions. Is there any way on this planet to get others users media from my access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API deprecated by instagram to fetching other's content.

Here is the detail from Instagram:-

```
Commenting on Public Content
GET /media/{media-id}/comments (Deprecation not relevant when fetching comments for self media)
POST /media/{media-id}/comments
DEL /media/{media-id}/comments/comment-id
```

For more details, you can go to page, This is effective from 4th April.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Comment: I'm always wondering how elfsight is working still :( 
https://elfsight.com/instagram-feed-instashow/#preview

Comment: There seems to be no replacement, so with Instagram you can't do things like [http://lush-kampagne.de/radfreude/]